# Why can't use ManagementObjectSearcher in VS2010 C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use the code from this post:
[get com port number of an USB adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163773/get-com-port-number-of-an-usb-adapter)

Then I got this message: why?
[image]

Comment: What about taking the message serious and add an assembly reference?

Comment: Did you add a reference to the System.Management namespace? Did you add a using directive?

Comment: Add Using, but not the reference. I fix this now. Thank you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to add a reference  to `System.Management` Manually through VS 2010.

1. Right Click on Project, **Add References**
2. Select the **Assemblies** Tab and Search for System.Management . Then Add Reference.

Comment: Thank you @Rajesh Subramanian.
I have several serial ports on my pc. I need list in the comboBox only the ports that has Friendly Name or Device Description == "USB Serial Port". Know how to do this or any link to learn?